# Entity Framework 5 - Many to Many relationship between multiple table using same intermediate table

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am trying to implement the below scenario using Entity Framework 5, with code first approach.

**Scenario**: I have three tables say

```
Table1: { Id1, Title }

Table2: { Id2, Title }

Table3: { Id3, Title }
```

and single intermediate table storing many-to-many relationship between "Table1 &Table2" and "Table2 & Table3". Say,

```
TableIntermediate: { FK1,  FK2 }
```

To specify the relation, On OnModelCreating(), I have specified two model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>()
                 .HasMany(c => c.Table2s)
                 .WithMany(pc => pc.Table1s)
                 .Map(m =>
                 {
                     m.ToTable("TableIntermediate");
                     m.MapLeftKey("FK1");
                     m.MapRightKey("FK2");
                 });

 modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>()
                 .HasMany(c => c.Table3s)
                 .WithMany(pc => pc.Table1s)
                 .Map(m =>
                 {
                     m.ToTable("TableIntermediate");
                     m.MapLeftKey("FK1");
                     m.MapRightKey("FK2");
                 });
```

Below are the entities defined:

```
public class Table1
 {
  public int Id1 {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}

  public ICollection<Table2> Table2s { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Table3> Table3s { get; set; }
 }

public class Table2
 {
  public int Id2 {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}
  public ICollection<Table1> Table1s { get; set; }
 }

public class Table3
 {
  public int Id3 {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}
  public ICollection<Table1> Table1s { get; set; }
 }
```

The code compiles properly. But at runtime throwing the error:

> {"Schema specified is not valid. Errors: \r\n(275,6) : error 0019: The EntitySet 'Table1Table2' with schema 'XXXX' and table 'TableIntermediate' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table."}

As we are using the exiting database, we want to store both the relations into a single intermediate table. The only solution I found is to introduce a new mapping table. Please let me know if the scenario is possible without introducing the new mapping table.